# How to change the text size in jQuery Mobile buttons, without altering the padding or margins?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I'm using css to style some buttons in grid and I need to make the text smaller in some buttons so it fits, but without changing the margins or padding.

I'm using this css and altering the font-size makes the entire button change slightly in size and also changes the padding and margins so they don't line up the same way on the grid.

```
.my_menu_btn{
    text-shadow:none !important;
    border-radius: 10px !important;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    font-weight: bold;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 1px lightgray;
    height:40px !important;
    box-sizing:border-box !important;
    max-width: 98% !important;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

Is there any way to alter the font without altering anything else. I don't really get why the font size alters the padding and margins anyway.

Comment: Font size doesn't alter padding or margin, they are the same just the font occupies less space and the element is getting smaller :) Try using line height to preserve the same height :)

Comment: Line height gets the buttons the same size but the margin between the bottom of a button and the top of the next is definitely affected.

Comment: Make an example in fiddle with your code and we can help you more :)

Comment: Solution has been provided below, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The margin/padding in jQM CSS uses the units **[em](http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/css2em.htm)** not pixels; and em is based on the current font-size. Therefore, when font-size is reduced, the effective margins are too.

Your workaround is to put the text within a span inside the button and then change the font size of the span:

```
<button ><span class="my_menu_btn">some longer text in span</span></button>

.my_menu_btn{
    font-size: 0.7em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/bkpzkhuw/2/)**

You can apply the rest of your CSS to the button:

```
button{
    text-shadow:none !important;
    border-radius: 10px !important;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 1px lightgray;
    box-sizing:border-box !important;
    max-width: 97% !important;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew it wasn't in my head!